# HR forgot about the video call interview

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I applied for a job, the recruiter got back to me after 2 weeks asking what time I could take the interview, I said whenever you want I could make time for it.

He told me he'd schedule a video call last Monday between 11am and 4pm, I said okay and gave him my Skype username in case he'd want to use Skype and told him that if he prefer to use another software to let me know so I could download it, he never replied.Sunday night the tech lead visited my LinkedIn.

Monday came I waited the entire time in front of my PC, not wanting to be unprofessional and not wanting to have to ask the HR to wait for me till I get to my PC, but nothing happened, but it was okay with me, since it was a national holiday so I thought maybe they didn't want to bother me during a holiday, today is Wednesday night and they haven't even emailed.

I do want the job, it's one of the biggest companies in my country but I have another job, so I'm fine if they don't want me.  What is the most professional thing to do now? Forget about it or email back?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere what to say? it's going to be awkward if I do that, I guess

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I truly think this is the best option, since people react differently when talking vs emailing, talking is always better than any other form of communication. I'll see what to do tomorrow. I already emailed him back per the answer the answer's recommendation, because I though you wouldn't reply back, and I saw the answer getting getting upvoted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your description, they didn't miss the meeting because you never actually got down to a specific hour, i.e. it was never finalized.  Absolutely email them back if you still want the job.

*Hey Mr. Recruiter, you talked earlier about scheduling a video call.  What's a good time for you?  I'm free [these days of the week] at [these hours].*

Comment: Although I prefer Joe's method better, talking is better than emailing, but I have nothing to say, emailing is more natural, I followed your advise and specified the date and time which suits me

Answer (score 1):

**Follow up with them.**

Stuff like this happens. Even Recruiters forget that they have to interview a client at X time. It happens, no fault of your own. This mostly happens because they get bogged down in work sometimes and they forget.